# JOIN triangle relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ienumerable

The relationship:

```
Profil>Branch>City
Profil>Hotel>City
```

command:

```
from p in Profil.getData()
join b in Branch.getData() on p equals b
join h in Hotel.getData() on p equals h
join c in City.getData()
                        ^how to reuse the equals join
```

Can I join City to Branch and Hotel table?
Can I just clone the c without City.getData()?

Comment: "Branch" of what?  Is it a "hotel" "branch"?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just do (following your pseudo code):

```
from p in Profil.getData()
join b in Branch.getData() on p equals b
join h in Hotel.getData() on p equals h
join c1 in City.getData() on b equals c1
join c2 in City.getData() on h equals c2
```

EF will translate this into two aliases for the City table. So you don't reuse or clone the cities, but in SQL that's not possible either. SQL server will be able to optimize it in the query's execution plan though.

Comment: `into` is basically turning a join into a [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), which creates a different grouping object than a `join`, but you'll still have to use two joins in your case.